# class method not returning sorted list in python

Tags: python, function, return, python-class

```
class Solution:
    def sortedSquares(self, numbs):
        n = len(numbs)
        for i in range(n):
            numbs[i] = numbs[i] * numbs[i]
        return numbs.sort()
    
sol = Solution()
nums = [-4,-1,0,3,10]
sol.sortedSquares(nums)
```

Class solution should return sorted list but returning nothing, I check the values of the nums list I got the correct output but I don't know why this method not returning sort list, I tried working around it by changing the variables declaration, but nothing helped.

Comment: `.sort()` doesn't return anything.  Either use `sorted` or split your sort and return into two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.sort() returns None

So, you want to use `sorted` instead:

```
class Solution:
    def sortedSquares(self, numbs):
        n = len(numbs)
        for i in range(n):
            numbs[i] = numbs[i] * numbs[i]
        return sorted(numbs)
    
sol = Solution()
nums = [-4,-1,0,3,10]
sol.sortedSquares(nums)
```

but if you do want to use .sort() still, just call the .sort() method and then return the numbs:

```
class Solution:
    def sortedSquares(self, numbs):
        n = len(numbs)
        for i in range(n):
            numbs[i] = numbs[i] * numbs[I]
        numbs.sort()
        return numbs
        
    
sol = Solution()
nums = [-4,-1,0,3,10]
sol.sortedSquares(nums)
```

Either way is fine.